# How to move container with moveToObject - Phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework

I have an enemy with a health bar. I want the health bar to move with the enemy. To do this I have made a container like this:﻿

```
var container = scene.add.container(x, y, [enemy, healthB﻿ar]);﻿﻿
```

This work just as expected, the problem is when I try to move the container with moveToObject like this:﻿﻿﻿

```
scene.physics.moveToObject(container, player, speed);
```

This does not work at all. How do I solve this?

Comment: What error do you have? I have a similar problem, I am trying to move a container to x, y and I receive `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'velocity' of null` - looks like the container does not have a body.

Answer (score 2):

```
scene.physics.world.enableBody(container);
```

enableBody(object [, bodyType]) - creates an Arcade Physics Body on a single Game Object.
And "moveToObject" will work.

Comment: I am not sure what the above comment does, but this answer solves my problem, I was looking for exactly that.